# Conditional logic to add class for specific section entries

Tags: entry, sections, conditional, logic

I'm trying to create a conditional logic so that the class 'white-nav-bg' is added to the  element on the 'blog' section entries only.

Below is the code I'm currently using to try and achieve this with a logic tag but it is adding the 'white-nav-bg' class to all pages on the site rather than just the blog section entry pages.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top
  {% for entry in craft.entries.section('blog').limit(1) %}
    {% if entry.type.handle == 'post' %}white-nav-bg{% endif %}
  {% endfor %}">
```

This code is in the '_layout.html' file, hence needing to figure out how to do conditional logic tags rather than adding the code differently in the blog template files.

After much time looking through Craft documentation I can't seem to find an example of how to do this. Any help would be gratefully received.

UPDATE:

Following helpful answers I have come to the following code, which works and allows me to define multiple sections to have the 'white-nav-bg' class.

```
{% set segment1 = craft.request.segment(1) %}
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top
  {% if segment1 == 'blog' %}
    white-nav-bg
  {% elseif segment1 == 'our-work' %}
    white-nav-bg
  {% endif %}">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do it based on segments:

```
{% set segment1 = craft.request.segment(1) %}

{% if segment1 == 'blah' %}
    do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. As Kaspar mentioned above, because it is in the _layout template this is a better approach. Is there a way to set multiple values in the 'blah' part? I'd like to do this for a few different sections.

Comment: You can use `getSegments` then call each segment the same just changing the segment number in the example I gave you.

Comment: Let me know if you need more info

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mark. So would I use the following to set each segment? {% set segment1 = craft.request.segment(1) %}{% if segment1 == 'blog' %}white-nav-bg{% elseif segment1 == 'ourWork' %}white-nav-bg{% endif %}

Comment: Actually, I've just figured it out and the following code works: {% set segment1 = craft.request.segment(1) %}{% if segment1 == 'blog' %}white-nav-bg{% elseif segment1 == 'our-work' %}white-nav-bg{% endif %} I'll update the question with the code that worked based on your answer

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities for this.

One of them is to listen to the section handle if you want it to be triggered only on the blog template:

```
{% if entry.section.handle == 'blog' %}your-class{% endif %}
```

Comment: Hi Kaspar, huge apologies for delayed response. Thank you for your helpful answer. It has partially worked but I am getting a template error on the Blog page now "Variable "entry" does not exist" - I'm assuming this is because my code is in the _layout template before I have set entry?

Comment: Yep. If you need this to be in the layout you can define a entry variable (Altough this isn't very pretty). `{% if entry is undefined %}{% set entry == x%}{% endif %}` But since you use it in layout I would go for the solution with the segments.